# Android Facebook sdk Stuck after public profile permission popup

Tags: android, android-facebook

I have been working with Facebook SDK for my current android project. I am facing some weird problems during Facebook login for first time, i.e. When i rum my code for the first time it asks for login and once login is successful , a popup appears asks for public profile permission when i agree a loading progress appears on popup endlessly, i cannot even cancel the popup. It does not go back to 'onActivityResult()' method of the calling activity. Ultimately i have to force stop my application.
But once i open my application again on phone now everything works fine and as expected.

I guess it is happening for the first time when application gets registered to facebook.

If i repeat the whole process , i.e. deleting application from facebook, logging out from device's facebook app, and uninstalling and re-installing my application again on phone, i face the same problem.

I am using Facebook SDK 3.5

Here is my code: activity's onCreate(...) method

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

          // callback when session changes state
          @Override
          public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            if (session.isOpened()) {

              // make request to the /me API
              Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                // callback after Graph API response with user object
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                  if (user != null) {
                    TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
                    welcome.setText("Hello " + user.getName() + "!");
                  }
                }
              }).executeAsync();
            }
          }
        });

}
```

onActivityResult(....) method

```
@Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      System.out.println("In on Activity Result");
      Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
  }
```

Comment: you are not using UILifeCycleHelper?

Comment: no i am not using it.... i am just running the sample code that is available in facebook tutorial in 'Getting Started' android sdk

Comment: well basically, it is very important for the flow between activity, and I believe if you have implemented it. you wont be in this situation

Comment: i will definitely try to implement UILifecyclehelper.. but i am facing this problem recently n only on some particular devices.. i have implemented facebook sdk 3.5 before in my previous application but never faced such thing and I am not using facebook login button instead i m using session login..

Comment: are using the same facebook credentials between the devices and does the mobile has a facebook app installed?

Comment: Yes i am using the same facebook credential n facebook app is already installed... as i mentioned in my question that it is happening only for the first time when user login's for the first time from the app and the application is not yet registered in his/her facebook account.. but once it gets registered on facebook there is no problem...

Comment: I also faced similar problem. My problem is even worse. Even after stopping the App and clear data/cache. still the permission popups comes. Its happening on My Gingerbird devices. I have another device with kitkat there everything running smoothly.

Comment: @Ramesh_D you must be using web view dialog for facebook login instead of using facebook app installed on your device. you can use LoginButton provided by facebook sdk. Using that button i never faced any problem but i dont want to use that button in my application.